# How do you solve Russian nesting dolls question with prolog?

Tags: prolog

Hi I am new to prolog and am trying to solve the question below:

```
/* 2. Russian nesting dolls:
 * Write a knowledge base using the predicate directlyIn/2 which encodes which doll 
 * is directly contained in which other doll. Then, define a recursive predicate in/2, 
 * that tells us which doll is (directly or indirectly) contained in which other dolls.*/

%% Predicates
directlyIn(katarina, olga).
directlyIn(olga, natasha).
directlyIn(natasha, irina).

%% Rules
in(X, Y) :- directlyIn(X, Y).
in(X,Y) :-
    directlyIn(X,Z),
    in(Z,Y).
```

Why does the following query return `false` instead of `true`?

```
?- in(katerina,natasha).
```

Comment: are you spelling it `katerina`  or `katarina` in your original query?

Comment: you are right, I spelled it wrong! :( THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing what you told us in your description, you said that the query:

```
?- in(katerina, natasha).
```

Returns `false`. But notice that spelling makes *all* difference. If you want to see results to "katerina", you should include this atom in your knowledge base, like this:

```
directlyIn(katarina, olga).  % All letters make difference here
directlyIn(katerina, olga).  % ?- katerina \== katarina. --> true.  They are different
```

Otherwise, just correct the name to "katarina" in your query and it will return the correct answer. Just in case you don't want to find more results after reaching the goal, you can put a simple `cut` operator (`!`) inside the base case of recursion rule:

```
in(X, Y) :- directlyIn(X, Y), !.  % Notice the '!' symbol, it tells the 
                                  % backtracking mechanism NOT to search 
                                  % for more answers to your query.
```